# Magento php calculation on the price

Tags: php, magento

i offer freeshipping on 50$ so have this code in checkout to inform the customers that their totals is less than 50$ and they should buy more to catch my offer.

```
   <?php $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
         $grandtotal = $totals["grand_total"]->getValue(); //Grandtotal value 
     if ($grandtotal >= 0 && $grandtotal < 50) {
     echo ' your totals is '; 
     echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($grandtotal , true, false);
     echo ' .Add some more products and you will have free shipping!';
}  ?>
```

so this will echo `your totals is 16.50$ .Add some more products and you will have free shipping!`
i was wondering how i can calculate the difference of 16.50$ - 50$ so the message will be :
`your totals is 16.50$ .Add 33.50$ more on your basket and you will have free shipping!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside if:

```
echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency(50-$grandtotal , true, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to create a constant first to define the value of 50 , it could be at the beginning of the class or in your constants class , for example `Constants::FREE_SHIPPING_VAL`, the reason for this is to avoid touching code in the future and have a central value that you can change only in one place so it will be replicated everywhere else.

then your code will be as following

```
 <?php $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
         $grandtotal = $totals["grand_total"]->getValue(); //Grandtotal value 
     if ($grandtotal >= 0 && $grandtotal < Constants::FREE_SHIPPING_VAL) {
     echo ' your totals is '; 
     $remaining = Mage::helper('core')->currency((Constants::FREE_SHIPPING_VAL-$grandtotal), true, false);
     echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($grandtotal , true, false);
     echo '.Add '.$remaining.' more on your basket and you will have free shipping!';
}  ?>
```